# Is it possible to upload xlsx file through Strapi admin panel?

Tags: cloudinary, strapi

I'm using Strapi CMS paired with Cloudinary for file storage. I've been uploading images just fine through the admin panel but I now need to be able to upload an xlsx file through the panel. I have had no luck with this

I know for a fact that Cloudinary supports xlsx files as I am able to upload my files through Cloudinary's console. However, whenever I try to upload it through Strapi, I get "Unsupported ZIP file" error.

I expected Strapi to be able to send my xlsx file to Cloudinary like it does with my images, since under the File Upload section of their docs, they state that "Thanks to the plugin Upload, you can upload any kind of files on your server or externals providers such as AWS S3".

I've been looking through their docs but I have not been able to find anything regarding file uploads that are not images. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading the xlsx file make sure you are setting the 'resource_type' to 'raw' as by default Cloudinary takes the resource_type as image.

Answer (score 0):

const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
req.file.path,

```
{ folder: "details" ,resource_type: 'auto' },

function (error, result) {
  console.log(result, error);
}
```

);